# Is it possible to rewrite this sum in terms of some power series?

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, power-series, summation-method

Is it possible to rewrite this sum in terms of some power series, maybe some cosine power series?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$$

Comment: This is a Bessel function

Comment: This is the $I_0(x)$ modified Bessel function. See [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25.ii). It is a non-elementary function.

Comment: How did you encounter that series? Bessel functions will likely be worth knowing for similar problems.